# Trigger.io reload channels do not have active users

Tags: reload, trigger.io

I am trying to test the Trigger.io reload function on my app, and have created a new stream but there are no active users for any of these channels.

Does code need to be added in the app to subscribe users to the reload streams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is a 15 minute delay in the reported user numbers.

However, if you have just installed a version of your app on a test device or run it in the emulator, you will be able to Reload it immediately even if the number of users showing up against the stream is still 0.

You do need to use the [forge.reload.switchStream](http://current-docs.trigger.io/modules/reload.html#switchstream) method in the app to put the user in the right stream. Or you can use the 'default' stream that is already there to reload all users without needing to add any extra code in your app.